# Is there a way to convert indentation in Python code to braces?

Tags: python

I am a totally blind programmer who would like to learn Python. Unfortunately the fact that code blocks are represented with different levels of indentation is a major stumbling block. I was wondering if there were any tools available that would allow me to write code using braces or some other code block delimiter and then convert that format into a properly indented representation that the Python interpreter could use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what operating system are you using?

Comment: But, why are spaces and line break a problem. Isn't it possible to make the text reader says unprintable chars ?

Comment: That seems like a recipe for disaster - I don't know many people who would like to listen to "space space space space space space space space def foo" before each line.

Comment: @javawizard it could work by stating " def foo colon, next line, increase of indentation, ..." or "indent level 0, def foo colon, next line indent level 1, ..."

Comment: @smoothdeveloper Absolutely, and that's what the poster's question is asking.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's a solution to your problem that is distributed with python itself. `pindent.py`, it's located in the Tools\Scripts directory in a windows install (my path to it is C:\Python25\Tools\Scripts), it looks like you'd have to [grab it from svn.python.org](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/pindent.py) if you are running on Linux or OSX.

It adds comments when blocks are closed, or can properly indent code if comments are put in. Here's an example of the code outputted by pindent with the command:

`pindent.py -c myfile.py`

```
def foobar(a, b):
   if a == b:
       a = a+1
   elif a < b:
       b = b-1
       if b > a: a = a-1
       # end if
   else:
       print 'oops!'
   # end if
# end def foobar
```

Where the original `myfile.py` was:

```
def foobar(a, b):
   if a == b:
       a = a+1
   elif a < b:
       b = b-1
       if b > a: a = a-1
   else:
       print 'oops!'
```

You can also use `pindent.py -r` to insert the correct indentation based on comments (read the header of pindent.py for details), this should allow you to code in python without worrying about indentation.

For example, running `pindent.py -r myfile.py` will convert the following code in `myfile.py` into the same properly indented (and also commented) code as produced by the `pindent.py -c` example above:

```
def foobar(a, b):
if a == b:
a = a+1
elif a < b:
b = b-1
if b > a: a = a-1
# end if
else:
print 'oops!'
# end if
# end def foobar
```

I'd be interested to learn what solution you end up using, if you require any further assistance, please comment on this post and I'll try to help.

Comment: Downvote: This *might* help with reading code, but it does not help with writing it. Python, and languages like it that depend solely on spacing to represent nesting are inherently broken when it comes to accessibility for the blind. A tool that performs the inverse of `pindent` on flush-left code (the preferred indentation scheme of many blind programmers) *might* be useful. More useful would be `from __future__ import braces` -- but not as an Easter egg.

Comment: @DavidHammen: There *is* a tool that performs the inverse of `pindent.py -c`; it's `pindent.py -r`. Ryan already noted that in their answer, but I just edited it to add an explicit example and make it harder to miss. (Also, I corrected the command-line option to do that: it's `-r`, not `-d` which just removes the comments.)

Answer (score 13):

I personally doubt that there currently is at the moment, as a lot of the Python afficionados love the fact that Python is this way, whitespace delimited.

I've never actually thought about that as an accessibility issue however. Maybe it's something to put forward as a bug report to Python?

I'd assume that you use a screen reader here however for the output? So the tabs would seem "invisible" to you? With a Braille output, it might be easier to read, but I can understand exactly how confusing this could be.

In fact, this is very interesting to me. I wish that I knew enough to be able to write an app that will do this for you.

I think it's definately something that I'll put in a bug report for, unless you've already done so yourself, or want to.

Edit: Also, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118643#118656) by [John Millikin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3560/john-millikin) There is also [PyBraces](http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/) Which might be a viable solution to you, and may be possible to be hacked together dependant on your coding skills to be exactly what you need (and I hope that if that's the case, you release it out for others like yourself to use)

Edit 2: I've just [reported this](http://bugs.python.org/issue3942) to the python bug tracker

Answer (score 10):

Although I am not blind, I have heard good things about [Emacspeak](http://emacspeak.sourceforge.net/). They've had a Python mode since their [8.0 release](http://emacspeak.sourceforge.net/releases/release-8.0.html) in 1998 (they seem to be up to release 28.0!). Definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to configure your editor to speak the tabs and spaces -- I know it's possible to *display* whitespace in most editors, so there must be an accessibility option somewhere to speak them.

Failing that, there is [pybraces](http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/), which was written as a practical joke but might actually be useful to you with a bit of work.

Comment: However, you've got to think of the fact that at a certain point, the remembering where you are in a code block dependant on tabs is going to be hard. Braces mark a specific start and end marker, whereas with tabs, it can be confusing (I get confused with it and I'm sighted!)

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Windows, I strongly recommend you take a look at EdSharp from:
http://empowermentzone.com/EdSharp.htm
It supports all of the leading Windows screenreaders, it can be configured to speak the indentation levels of code, or it has a built in utility called PyBrace that can convert to and from braces syntax if you want to do that instead, and it supports all kinds of other features programmers have come to expect in our text editors.  I've been using it for years, for everything from PHP to JavaScript to HTML to Python, and I love it.

Comment: I've been using it as my main editor for the last year or so.

Answer (score 5):

All of these "no you can't" types of answers are really annoying. Of course you can.

It's a hack, but you can do it.

http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/

uses a custom encoding to convert braces to indented blocks before handing it off to the interpreter.

---

As an aside, and as someone new to python - I don't accept the reasoning behind not even *allowing* braces/generic block delimiters ... apart from that being the preference of the python devs. Braces at least won't get eaten accidentally if you're doing some automatic processing of your code or working in an editor that doesn't understand that white space is important. If you're generating code automatically, it's handy to not have to keep track of indent levels. If you want to use python to do a perl-esque one-liner, you're automatically crippled. If nothing else, just as a safeguard. What if your 1000 line python program gets all of its tabs eaten? You're going to go line-by-line and figure out where the indenting should be?

Asking about it will invariably get a tongue-in-cheek response like "just do 'from __ future __ import braces'", "configure your IDE correctly", "it's better anyway so get used to it" ...

I see their point, but hey, if i wanted to, i could put a semicolon after every single line. So I don't understand why everyone is so adamant about the braces thing. If you need your language to force you to indent properly, you're not doing it right in the first place.

Just my 2c - I'm going to use braces anyway.

Comment: you need to open a python shell and enter:  import this

Comment: Indeed, my opinion has been swayed through experience. I was trying to find a way to force python to conform to the needs of one of my projects and was frustrated to find that it refused to do so by any means of persuasion. I've come at it from a different angle and have found python to be a beautiful and highly cooperative platform to work in. The main lesson I've learned is that cheap hacks and computers don't mix well. I've had to do some in-depth study of parsing algorithms, but the knowledge I've gained is well worth it. I still don't care for indent/dedent, but I respect them.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate your problem, but think you are specifying the implementation instead of the problem you need solved.  Instead of converting to braces, how about working on a way for your screen reader to tell you the indentation level?

For example, [some people](http://viming.blogspot.com/2007/02/indent-level-highlighting.html) have worked on vim syntax coloring to represent python indentation levels.  Perhaps a modified syntax coloring could produce something your screen reader would read?

Comment: "level 4 indentation" foo equals new bar
"level 3 indentation" 

It's confusing, and having to keep track of that in your mind is an extra burden.

Comment: Not "level N indentation", "in" vs. "out", or "indent" vs. "dedent" should be enough.

def foo ( x ) : indent return x * 2 dedent

Answer (score 4):

Searching an accessible Python IDE, found this and decided to answer.
Under Windows with JAWS:

1. Go to Settings Center by pressing <kbd>JawsKey</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (on the number row above the letters) in your favorite text editor. If JAWS prompts to create a new configuration file, agree.
2. In the search field, type "indent"
3. There will be only one result: "Say indent characters". Turn this on.
4. Enjoy!

The only thing that is frustrating for us is that we can't enjoy code examples on websites (since indent speaking in browsers is not too comfortable — it generates superfluous speech).

Happy coding from another Python beginner).

Answer (score 3):

I use eclipse with the pydev extensions since it's an IDE I have a lot of experience with. I also appreciate the smart indentation it offers for coding if statements, loops, etc. I have configured the pindent.py script as an external tool that I can run on the currently focused python module which makes my life easier so I can see what is closed where with out having to constantly check indentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are various answers explaining how to do this. But I would recommend not taking this route. While you could use a script to do the conversion, it would make it hard to work on a team project.

My recommendation would be to configure your screen reader to announce the tabs.  This isn't as annoying as it sounds, since it would only say "indent 5" rather than "tab tab tab tab tab". Furthermore, the indentation would only be read whenever it changed, so you could go through an entire block of code without hearing the indentation level. In this way hearing the indentation is no more verbose than hearing the braces.

As I don't know which operating system or screen reader you use I unfortunately can't give the exact steps for achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

[Edsger Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) used [if ~ fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Selection:_if) and [do ~ od](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Repetition:_do) in his "Guarded Command Language", these appear to originate from the [Algol68](https://sourceforge.net/projects/algol68/).  There were also some example python guarded blocks used in [RosettaCode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Python).

```
fi = od = yrt = end = lambda object: None;
class MyClass(object):
    def myfunction(self, arg1, arg2):
        for i in range(arg1) :# do
            if i > 5 :# then
                print i
            fi
        od # or end(i) #
    end(myfunction)
end(MyClass)
```

Whitespace mangled python code can be unambiguously unmangled and reindented if one uses
guarded blocks if/fi, do/od & try/yrt together with semicolons ";" to separate statements.  Excellent for unambiguous magazine listings or cut/pasting from web pages.

It should be easy enough to write a short python program to insert/remove the guard blocks and semicolons.

Comment: Impractical but interesting approach. Upvoted