# Meaning of keyword "in" in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I am just starting to learn F#.  In several F# coding examples I see the keyword "in" used in the following way:

```
let doStuff x =
    let first, second = x in
    first + " " + second
```

The function works with and without the "in" at then end of the second line.  What does "in" do?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`in` is a hangover from F#'s OCaml roots and it specifies *bound* variables, which are subtly different to variable *scopes*.

Think of variable binding as follows; You have an expression:

```
first + " " + second
```

As it stands `first` and `second` are unbound - they don't have any fixed values - so that expression has no concrete value at present. By using

```
let (...) in
```

syntax you are specifying how those variables are bound **in that expression**, so your example will use variable substitution to reduce that function down to

```
let doStuff x =
  x + " " + x
```

---

In this example both forms are identical, but imagine the following:

```
let (x = 2 and y = x + 2) in
     y + x
```

This will not work the same as

```
let (x = 2 and y = x + 2)
     y + x
```

Because in the former case `x` is only bound **after** the `in` keyword.

In the later case normal variable *scoping* rules take effect, so variables are bound as soon as they are declared.

Hope that clears things up. In general you should always use the version *without* `in` and specify `#light` at the start of your F# source files

Comment: I do not think the code in the question is equivalent to `let doStuff x = x + " " + x`. I believe it is equivalent to `let doStuff x = (fst x) + " " + (snd x)`. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Mark, this was long ago, but those examples don't work in F# and I think they may never have. Is this OCaml only syntax? Also, with "different", do you mean one compiles in OCaml, but the other doesn't? Because otherwise I don't see how they can have different results.

Comment: @Mark please edit this so people don’t waste time trying to understand it only to find that it is irrelevant in 2023.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another related thread here on SO that could be also useful:

- [F# - Should I learn with or without #light?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461739/f-should-i-learn-with-or-without-light/461929#461929)

Answer (score 6):

To quote from [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/fsharp_v1.1.12/FSharp-1.1.12.3/manual/lexyacc.html).

> When the light syntax option is
> enabled 'in' is optional. The token after the '='
> of a 'let' definition begins a new block, where
> the pre-parser inserts an implicit separating 'in'
> token between each 'let' binding that begins at
> the same column as that token.
>
> Without the light syntax option 'in'
> is very often required. The 'in' is
> optional when  the light syntac option
> is used.

So I'm guessing you're using light syntax.