# What does the 'in' keyword do in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm reading the book Expert F# from Apress and there is a snippet there that I don't truly understand:

```
let powerOfFour n =
    let nSquared = n * n in nSquared * nSquared

Console.WriteLine(powerOfFour 2)
```

What is the 'in' keywords doing here, and does it allow me to call a method inside of the method itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of keyword "in" in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546287/meaning-of-keyword-in-in-f)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`in` is the moral equivalent of a newline after a `let`.  This is the same as

```
let nSquared = n * n
nSquared * nSquared
```

except all on one line.  You can read some more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx

which shows off many of the 'verbose' keywords that you don't need when you just let the indentation do the work.