# What's the meaning of the `in` keyword in this example (F#)

Tags: f#, keyword

I've been trying to get my head round various bits of F# (I'm coming from more of a C# background), and parsers interest me, so I jumped at this blog post about F# parser combinators:

http://santialbo.com/blog/2013/03/24/introduction-to-parser-combinators

One of the samples here was this:

```
/// If the stream starts with c, returns Success, otherwise returns Failure
let CharParser (c: char) : Parser<char> =
    let p stream =
        match stream with
        | x::xs when x = c -> Success(x, xs)
        | _ -> Failure
    in p               //what does this mean?
```

However, one of the things that confused me about this code was the `in p` statement. I looked up the `in` keyword in the MSDN docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx

I also spotted this earlier question:

[Meaning of keyword "in" in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546287/meaning-of-keyword-in-in-f)

Neither of those seemed to be the same usage. The only thing that seems to fit is that this is a pipelining construct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `let x = ... in expr` allows you to declare a binding for some variable `x` which can then be used in expr.

In this case `p` is a function which takes an argument `stream` and then returns either `Success` or `Failure` depending on the result of the match, and this function is returned by the `CharParser` function.

The F# [light syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx) automatically nests `let .. in` bindings, so for example

```
let x = 1
let y = x + 2
y * z
```

is the same as

```
let x = 1 in
let y = x + 2 in
y * z
```

Therefore, the `in` is not needed here and the function could have been written simply as

```
let CharParser (c: char) : Parser<char> =
    let p stream =
        match stream with
        | x::xs when x = c -> Success(x, xs)
        | _ -> Failure
    p
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is the same use case as the SO question I had a link to, though the code layout was slightly different.

Answer (score 9):

The answer from Lee explains the problem. In F#, the `in` keyword is heritage from earlier functional languages that inspired F# and  required it - namely from ML and OCaml.

It might be worth adding that there is just one situation in F# where you still need `in` - that is, when you want to write `let` followed by an expression on a *single line*. For example:

```
let a = 10
if (let x = a * a in x = 100) then printfn "Ok"
```

This is a bit funky coding style and I would not normally use it, but you do need `in` if you want to write it like this. You can always split that to multiple lines though:

```
let a = 10
if ( let x = a * a
     x = 100 ) then printfn "Ok"
```

Comment: Yeah the use of in really does not make that any more readable. I take it that in your example doing something like `if ( a * a = 100 ) then printfn "Ok"` would achieve the same thing?