# Map sequence of pixels to their colours

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I have a sequence of elements `[(12, 34); (56, 78); ...]` and I want to turn it into `[(XXX, XXX, XXX); (XXX, XXX, XXX); ...]` where `(XXX, XXX, XXX)` is the (R, G, B) of the given tuple/coordinates, e.g., `(12, 34)`. According to .NET documentation, `System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel` returns `System.Drawing.Color` and you can just call `Color.R`, `Color.B` and `Color.G` to get the colour value as a `byte`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
let neighbourColor (img : System.Drawing.Bitmap) (s : seq<int * int>) =
 s |> Seq.collect(fun e -> s |> img.GetPixel(fst(e), snd(e)) |> Seq.map(fun c -> (c.R, c.G, c.B)))
```

For every element `e` in sequence `s`, get the color of e which is a tuple of coordinates on image `img`, then pass it to `Seq.map` to transform it into (Red, Green, Blue) and collect it as a new sequence `neighbourColor`.

Basically I want to turn `seq<int*int>` into `seq<byte*byte*byte>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let neighbourColor (img:Bitmap) coords =
   coords |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> let c = img.GetPixel (x, y) in c.R, c.G, c.B)
```

In general, it is probably better style to only explicitly specify a parameter's type when it cannot be inferred (in this case `coords` is already implicitly understood to be a `seq<int*int>`).

Comment: [Meaning of keyword “in” in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546287/meaning-of-keyword-in-in-f)

Comment: @ChaosPandion : I only used it here because I was going for a one-liner. :-]

Comment: Just wanted to make it convenient for people to understand the syntax as it is used rarely.

Comment: let neighbourColor (img : System.Drawing.Bitmap) (s : seq<int * int>) =
 s |> Seq.map(fun(i, j) -> (img.GetPixel(i, j).R, img.GetPixel(i, j).G, img.GetPixel(i, j).B)) //I figured it out, but yours is cleaner.

Comment: @user3487239 : And also more efficient - `GetPixel` is a _very_ expensive call, so calling it only once vs. thrice will likely have a noticeable impact.

Comment: Is system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits the faster way to go if I want recolor an entire image without using get/set pixel.

Comment: @user3487239 : Yes, by orders of magnitude. Just hope you don't have more than one type of palette. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

```
let (|RGB|) (c:Color)=RGB(c.R,c.G,c.B)
let Test (img:Bitmap)=Seq.map (img.GetPixel>>function RGB(r,g,b)->r,g,b)
```