# f#: Strange syntax in example using ".. in let .."

Tags: f#, rosetta-code

I am reading through an example on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Functional) and do not exactly know what the following line is doing.

```
let min,subheap = findMin heap' in let rtn = root topnode
```

It seems that `findMin heap'` is self contained unit of execution. I do not know how it relates to the "in" operator nor do I understand the use of the let statement in the "in" operator.

Here is the whole method

```
let rec private findMin heap =
  match heap with | [] -> raise Empty_Heap //guarded so should never happen
                  | [node] -> root node,[]
                  | topnode::heap' ->
                    let min,subheap = findMin heap' in let rtn = root topnode
                    match subheap with
                      | [] -> if rtn.k > min.k then min,[] else rtn,[]
                      | minnode::heap'' ->
                        let rmn = root minnode
                        if rtn.k <= rmn.k then rtn,heap
                        else rmn,minnode::topnode::heap''
```

[Edit] Even after sepp2k explained it, the documentation for "let" does not explain this. You have to look at that ["Verbose Syntax (F#)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I think you can read `in` as a newline in this case, i.e. it would be equivalent if you replaced `in` with a linefeed + indentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of keyword "in" in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546287/meaning-of-keyword-in-in-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verbose syntax for `let` expressions is `let <ident> = <exp> in <exp>`. So to define and add two variables you could write `let x = 23 in let y = 42 in x + y`. The light syntax of F# allows you to leave out the `in` at the end of a line, so this example would instead be written as:

```
let x = 23
let y = 42
x + y
```

Your code mixed the verbose and the light syntax by keeping the first `in` to be able to have the two `let`s in a single line.