# F# let binding patterns

Tags: f#

The problem is not new in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546287/meaning-of-keyword-in-in-f), but I am not able to comprehend the behavior of `let` binding with patterns and of the `in` keyword.
My [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534952119) prefers the uncommon function definition format:

```
let foo = fun x -> let f = (fun x y -> x +y ) in f x
```

So that I translated in #light syntax:

```
let foo x =
    let f y =
        x + y
    f x
```

If I set `foo 4` it returns me `8`. Why? I cannot comprehend what actually happens inside the function, even with the elegant explications from [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/let-use-do/). Why `4` becomes argument for both `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining a function inside another function, your inner function `f` captures a value from the outer function, the value `x` which is used in `x + y` so `x` becomes 4.

Then you call the inner function `f x` passing `x` to `y` which is also 4.

Another way to view it, without taking in account the specific value 4, your inner function is `let f y = x + y` but it's always called with `x` so `y` becomes `x`, then your function becomes something like `let f a = a + a`.

The key thing to understand this is that a function can capture a value from the context, in this case `x`.

So this explains the behavior of your function using the light syntax but you might be wondering why it differs from the one-liner version. It's because the translation is wrong. Here's the right translation:

```
let foo x =
    let f x y = 
        x + y
    f x
```

And now if you call it with `foo 4` it returns a function that expect the other parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Say we call the function foo with 4.

```
let foo x =
    let f y =
        x + y
    f x

foo 4
```

We can replace `foo 4` with the function `foo` replacing all the `x` with 4.

```
let f y =
    4 + y

f 4
```

Now we can replace `f 4` with the function `f` with `y := 4`.

```
4 + 4
```

Which is obviously 8.