# If #light syntax is so much better in F#, why isn't it the default?

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm digging F# and enjoying writing code in massively different ways.

But I'm confused - why the non #light syntax exists if it is superior to the default syntax?

Does anyone know why?

Why not make #light default and allow a #dark option for those wanted whitespace inspecific code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the default in the latest CTP release and will be when it is in the box for Visual Studio 2010.

While most developers agree with you that #light is a more pleasant coding experience, not everyone shares your love. Moreover, having whitespace aware code also makes some tasks such as code generation MUCH more difficult. (Think lambdas inside of lambdas.)

I suspect the non-#light won't be discussed or seen in the wild, but will certainly exist for people who come from a heavy OCaml background or have some religious issues with #light.

Comment: There are also those of us who did FORTRAN before it became form-free and have an irrational fear of having to punch each line of code starting at column 8 again... Took a while to get used to whitespace sensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

The non-light syntax exist for OCaml compatability. F# takes some code for libraries directly from OCaml and also is supposed to be compatible with OCaml. If you want to port code you just use non-light. As stated in the previous answer #light will be the default in the final release.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you missed that, you can find some more thoughts about the #light syntax in another post [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461739/f-should-i-learn-with-or-without-light/461929). It explains some reasons why non-#light syntax may be interesting.