# Why is ";;" required in F# interactive?

Tags: f#, ironpython, f#-interactive

Why is ";;" required in F# interactive at the end of a command? For instance, IronPython doesn't require it?

EDIT:
[When do you put double semicolons in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669299/when-do-you-put-double-semicolons-in-f/2669731#2669731)
covers most of the historical background

I guess my point was if you are using mostly one-liners in interactive it's cumbersome; however I see the value of ';;' when building functions interactively.

Comment: because they are different languages with different syntaxes.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, I believe that this was inherited from OCaml - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669731/82959.

Answer (score 2):

How does the compiler know when you want to end your function - both of these are valid

```
let func() =
    System.Console.Read() |> ignore
```

and

```
let func() =
    System.Console.Read() |> ignore
    1
```

So we need `;;` to know where the function ends

Comment: Arguably the REPL could defer until another top-level statement is entered.