# F# Command Line Interactive Repl

Tags: linux, f#

I'm on linux and I'd like to use an interactive command line repl for F#.

For example, like the node repl.

What options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TheQuickBrownFox has a good suggestion, but sometimes I find it's easier to type a quick bit of test code into an actual REPL rather than editing an .fsx file in VS Code. The F# REPL is available with the `fsharpi` command. It's part of the `fsharp` package (at least on Debian-based systems) so you should already have it installed.

Comment: And if not, a simple `sudo apt-get install fsharp` should do it.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot rmunn. Although I did find it weird that every line needs to end with a double semi-colon, ie. printf "Hello World";;

Comment: The double-semicolon is [an artifact of F#'s history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669299/when-do-you-put-double-semicolons-in-f), specifically its early attempts at being compatible with OCaml. More details at the link.

Comment: I'm guessing the fsharp package has been superseded by the F# SDK (see Chris K answer)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than typing directly into a REPL, I recommend creating an F# script file (.fsx) in an editor with F# support, e.g. Visual Studio Code. Then you can type script code with the usual benefits type-checking and auto-completions, and just select sections of code and send them to FSI (F# Interactive), usually by pressing Alt-Enter.

Comment: No doubt the better way.

Answer (score 2):

Under openSUSE Leap 15.3 the command is `dotnet fsi`.
(Having followed these [F# SDK installation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-opensuse).)

Comment: For Arch as well.

Comment: Couldn't find rmunn's fsharp package on Debian but did find Chris K's answer (dotnet fsi)