# Why are braces allowed in this Python code?

Tags: python, curly-braces

Python has never used braces to define code blocks, it relies on indentation instead; this is one of the defining features of the language. There's even a little cookie that CPython gives you to show how strongly they feel about this:

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

When I saw this little snippet posted to a forum (since deleted) I thought it cannot possibly work. But it does!

```
>>> def hi(): {
    print('Hello')
    }

>>> hi()
Hello
```

Why does this code work, when it appears to violate the language syntax?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs just as an extra answer in any one of the dozens of other threads about braces in Python, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118643/is-there-a-way-to-convert-indentation-in-python-code-to-braces ... especially as it was asked and answered immediately by the same user, meaning it's more of a curiosity than a genuine document describing a real question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert indentation in Python code to braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118643/is-there-a-way-to-convert-indentation-in-python-code-to-braces)

Comment: @ely the other questions are about why braces *aren't* allowed. If you find one that asks why they *are* allowed, that would be a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't say it was a duplicate. The answer should be just an extra side-note on the questions asking *how* to use braces for indentation. Those questions aren't asking about why braces aren't allowed, they are asking how to use braces. So valid answers would be using third-party extensions like pybraces, or this answer, but it clearly isn't a separate question.

Comment: @ely this question is very specific: it's about a particular piece of code which is not using *any* extensions, which at first glance appears to violate the language syntax.

Comment: @ely my apologies, it appears I worded the question in an ambiguous way. I wasn't asking how to make this code work, I was asking why it *does* work. I've updated the last sentence to make it more clear.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think the intent of the question (to ask about this specific occurrence of braces) was clear already -- and that this specific question is just subsumed by the already existing questions about valid uses of curly braces that superficially simulate the idea of a code block from other languages. In other words, the question as it's asked (why does one specific syntactical use of braces appear to work) should be closed in the sense that it's clearly not a separate question from many other threads on this topic. Just my opinion though.

Answer (score 5):

The braces aren't defining a code block as they would in other languages - they're defining a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). The `print` function is being evaluated and its return value (`None`) is being placed in the set. Once the set is created it is immediately discarded since it isn't being assigned to anything.

There are a couple of Python syntax features that are being exploited here. First, Python allows a single-statement code block to come immediately after a `:`. Second, an expression is allowed to span multiple lines under certain circumstances.

This code wouldn't have worked if the body of the block were more than one line, or if an assignment or statement other than a function call were attempted.

Here's a redoing of the function to make it clearer what's happening:

```
>>> def hi2(): print(
    { print('Hello') }
    )

>>> hi2()
Hello
{None}
```